# Saving persistent cookies on Android Native apps

Tags: java, android, cookies, session-cookies, android-cookiemanager

When developing for a browser, cookies are seamless.
However, as I'm finding out, when developing native java apps for android this is a whole new story.

What is the best way to store **Persistant** cookies on android?

I send both session and regular cookies from the server to the app.
I need the session cookies gone when the app closes / phone is restarted but
i need the other cookies to stay. As it is now, cookies are in memory and are gone after a phone restart.

please advise.

Thanks